# Can an algorithm tested only on artificial data be accepted in a high rank conference?

Tags: algorithms, model-evaluations

I devised a classification algorithm which is useful for specific complicated distribution of classes of data. The method works good on the artificial data which cannot be solved by typical algorithms in the literature. But yet i couldn't find any real data to evaluate the algorithm on real problems.
Also there is mathematical support for the basis of the approach and the way it works. 
So i was wondering if an algorithm with good mathematical support but no evaluation on real data has any chance to get accepted in computer science conferences like **SDM** or **CVPR**?